# problems when installing gitlab on ubuntu14.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gitlab

I want to install gitlab on Ubuntu 14.04, and i have installed postfix and openssh-server. I also downloaded the "gitlab-ce_7.10.5~omnibus-1_amd64.deb" (the steps are on [this page](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404)).
Then I typed: `dpkg -i /home/gary/下载/gitlab-ce_7.10.5~omnibus-1_amd64.deb`

The output was as follows:

```
gary@gitlab:~$ sudo dpkg -i /home/gary/下载/gitlab-ce_7.10.5~omnibus-1_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for gary: 
Selecting previously unselected package gitlab-ce.
(正在读取数据库 ... 系统当前共安装有 173323 个文件和目录。)
Preparing to unpack .../gitlab-ce_7.10.5~omnibus-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gitlab-ce (7.10.5~omnibus-1) ...
正在设置 gitlab-ce (7.10.5~omnibus-1) ...
dpkg-query: package 'gitlab' is not installed
使用 dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) 来检测打包好的文件，
还可以通过 dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) 来列出它们的内容。
gitlab: Thank you for installing GitLab!
gitlab: Configure and start GitLab by running the following command:
gitlab: 
gitlab: sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
gitlab: 
gitlab: GitLab should be reachable at http://gitlab.ng60.com
gitlab: Otherwise configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file
gitlab: And running reconfigure again.
gitlab: 
gitlab: For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme
gitlab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md
gitlab: 
It looks like GitLab has not been installed yet; skipping the upgrade script.
```

It seems that the installation failed and gitlab was not installed.
Is that true?
I'm confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to just say that as it was not installed before, no upgrade scripts were run.

Check `apt-cache show gitlab` output.
It should say: `Status: install ok config-files` on the second line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.